Asian movie about an ex hitman who kills a criminal organization
Year: before 2008
Country of release: Not sure China or Japan.
Genre: Action
Main character: An Asian ex hitman. He retired, got married with a Japanese woman, plays baseball as a past time. While washing his back in the bathtub, his wife tells him she's pregnant.
Scene Opening: An assassin (not the protagonist) goes into a restaurant, stick his chewing gum to a pole, puts on a scuba suit, dive into a huge and deep aquarium (that reaches all the way to the basement floor), and with a rifle kills all the underground bosses that were in a meeting. He later dies in a purikura that was bomb-rigged.
Plot: Can't remember much, but the main protagonist had to say farewell to his wife on the phone (silently) and goes to kill a criminal organization (which he would later die from).
